# Is there any charting library for IPhone can build a chart like bloomberg financial's chart?

Tags: iphone, charts, multi-touch

I am finding a charting library for IPhone which can build a chart similar to Bloomberg Financial' chart but still not find out yet, Core-Plot is a powerful library but it is not support zoom using multi-touch. Is there anybody know about this please help me!

You can watch this video to know about Bloomberg's chart:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_iNKZaji8k&feature=related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is core-plot: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Comment: Thanks Eiko, I knew this one already, as I mentioned that it is a powerful charting library but it not support zooming use multi-touch

Comment: I didn't see multitouch zoom in the video either. If you want the whole thing to zoom it should be easy to wrap into a scrollview. If you only want to change the visible data but keep it in place, hook up gesture recognizers and update the data for the chart.

Comment: @Son Nguyen - If you want to do a line chart with gradient shading, like you find in the Bloomberg chart, Core Plot is the only open source framework capable of that on the iPhone that I'm aware of.  Pinch-zooming has been implemented by several users, but it not part of the mainline codebase as of the last time I checked.  You're welcome to help us implement it.

Comment: Dear Eiko, I gave an incorrect link, I had updated the video's link, please take a look again.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_iNKZaji8k&feature=related

Comment: That looks really good. I haven't used core-plot myself yet and I'm short on time, but from glancing over the code it should be possible to add this functionality. Maybe the core-plot guys can help you out, or offer some cash for the person who adds this.

Comment: I am looking at the core-plot library with some help from Michele Colombo, the zoom function using multi-touch is done now!